# Latitude and longitude wise distrubution

Tags: r, google-maps

Currently I am dealing with latitude and longitude data set. Where I want to study lat/lon wise distribution and find out the nearest point of each lat/lon. I have done couple of things but still I am facing some issue. My dataset is given below

```
Latitude    Longitude
38.929596   -77.2478813
38.929596   -77.2478813
38.9295887  -77.2478945
38.9295048  -77.247922
38.9294865  -77.2479055
38.9294865  -77.2479055
38.9294865  -77.2479055
38.9294773  -77.2478712
38.9294773  -77.2478712
38.9294773  -77.2477417
38.9294773  -77.2477417
38.9292972  -77.247649
38.9292972  -77.247649
38.9292972  -77.247649
38.9291838  -77.2475982
38.9291838  -77.2475982
38.9290903  -77.2467052
38.9289893  -77.2462247
38.9290013  -77.2462322
38.9290008  -77.2462207
38.9290468  -77.2456722
```

1. Assuming each row consist 1 point.

So, final data frame looks like (for nearest point wise)

```
No  Latitude    Longitude      nearest_points(lat)  nearest_points(lon)   Distance
1   38.929596   -77.2478813          .....                ....              ...
2   38.929596   -77.2478813
3   38.9295887  -77.2478945
4   38.9295048  -77.247922
5   38.9294865  -77.2479055
6   38.9294865  -77.2479055
7   38.9294865  -77.2479055
8   38.9294773  -77.2478712
9   38.9294773  -77.2478712
10  38.9294773  -77.2477417
11  38.9294773  -77.2477417
12  38.9292972  -77.247649
13  38.9292972  -77.247649
14  38.9292972  -77.247649
15  38.9291838  -77.2475982
16  38.9291838  -77.2475982
17  38.9290903  -77.2467052
18  38.9289893  -77.2462247
19  38.9290013  -77.2462322
20  38.9290008  -77.2462207
21  38.9290468  -77.2456722
```

2. What is the meaning of distribution?Is it a simple histogram?

The code is given below - 
2.

```
data = read.csv('Data.csv')

library(raster)
distribution <- pointDistance(data[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")], lonlat=TRUE)

distribution_matrix <- as.matrix(as.dist(distribution))
diag(distribution_matrix) <- NA
```

Now I create a nxn matrix for distribution purpose i.e. calculating distance from each point.Now how to measure the distribution in R?

1.Also calculate the nearest point. The code is -

```
i <- apply(distribution_matrix, 1, which.min)

p <- cbind(1:nrow(distribution_matrix), i)  

distribution_matrix[p]
apply(distribution_matrix, 1, min, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But this is not like my final output. I want in data frame format with distance.

Comment: *nearest* to what? The equator and prime-meridian intersection?

Comment: @r2evans - it's a distance..nearest distance between two points

Comment: Sorry, but *"find the nearest point of each lat/long"* is a bit vague and context-specific. Okay, that's fine, this seems relatively classical `dist`ance with a haversine function, is that it?

Comment: @r2evans - you are right...actually my goal is to do clustering...but before that I want to measure the distance of each point and want to know the closest pair points.Another thing is "pointDistance" gives me km/meter wise distance?

Answer (score 0):

> But I do not like my final output. I want in data frame format with
>   distance.

You can make a data.frame from the output.

```
i <- apply(distribution_matrix, 1, which.min)
j <- apply(distribution_matrix, 1, min, na.rm=TRUE)

dd <- data.frame(data, nearpoint=i, dist=j)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.Just two quick questions -
i.How to measure the distribution?
ii.What is the unit of distance?It's a meter or kilometer?

Comment: "distribution" is a broad term that can be measured in different ways. You can edit your question to explain what you are after. Some measure of spatial distribution or clustering perhaps? The unit is meter; see `?pointDistance`

Comment: RobertH - Thanks for your valuable help.My final object is to do clustering but before that I want to study the spatial distribution.How to do it in R?